# How to add a Class Rule in Jquery Validation

Tags: class, jquery-validate

I'm trying to add a class rule instead of a name rule in jquery validate but cannot seems to get the aspect of it.

```
    form.validate({
        //NAME RULE
        rules: {
            //profile
            first: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },

        },
       //CLASS RULE 
       addClassRules: {
            receive: {
                minlength: 2,
                required: true
            },
        },

    });
```

am i doing this correctly?

Reference : http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/

Comment: I guess you didn't read the reference [you've linked to in your OP](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/).

Comment: i did read it and also implemented it, the problem is it isn't validating together with the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addClassRules` method does not belong inside of `.validate()`.

```
form.validate({
    //NAME RULE
    rules: {
        //profile
        first: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

[As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/), it gets attached to the validator object to create the compound rule that represents the standard rules specified inside.

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("myCompundRule", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
});
```

Usage is as simple as applying the new `class` to your `input`.

```
<input type="text" class="myCompundRule" name="somename" />
```

Comment: my problem with this is that it isn't validating with the form

Comment: and also it doesn't work for if i make it for multiple types of classes

Comment: @usee3261755, you only asked what you were doing wrong and I showed you.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('input[id*="vital"]').each(function () {
    sr=$(this).attr("data-startrange");
    //console.log(sr);
    er=$(this).attr("data-endrange");
    $('.addEnc').rules('add', {
        required: true,
         range:[sr,er]

    });
});
```

Comment: sr=starting range , er= ending range
sr define in data atrribute i.e <input class="input-small" data-startrange="<?= $vital['starting_range']; ?>"  data-endrange="<?= $vital['ending_range']; ?>"  id="vital<?= $vital['id']; ?>" name="vital[<?= $vital['id']; ?>][0]" type="Number" placeholder=<?= $vital['placeholder_text']; ?> value=""/>

Comment: Please don't toss out code, provide an answer that explains why the code is useful. Educate so that the OP understands how to do it and what's happening.